# Mutual TLS authentication via Reverse Proxy with Non-http(s) TCP Protol

Tags: ssl

I have an application which accepts messages (TCP) over TLS from client Server. With NGINX, I want to terminate TLS at NGINX and then NGINX will forward the decrypted packets second layer NGINX reverse proxy and then finally to the application. Please note my application does NOT receive message over HTTP, but over TCP (Hence HTTP(S) related modules are not valid for my use case). 
Client Server --(TLS)--> NGINX --(Decrypted) ---> NGINX --> Application Server

Question is how TLS handshake happens between these two app Severs via Proxies ?How this works ? where to install Server side SSL Certificate ? On NGINX Proxy or on Application Server ?